# What is an "Unused suppression" in FlowType?

Tags: flowtype

I got this error:

```
src/WorkEntryMain.jsx:33
 33: /*
     ^ Error suppressing comment. Unused suppression
```

Not sure what it means.

Comment: What is in the rest of that comment, and what is the line after it?

Comment: Shoot. I don't remember. I ended up deleting the comment (it was an entire function commented out). And there error went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [suppression comment](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) suppresses any Flow type errors on the line after it. If there are no errors on the line after it, Flow will tell you that it is unused.

Comment: Oh duh! I didn't put two and two together. I actually blogged about that in March: https://medium.com/@daveford/suppress-an-error-in-flow-68b38b032afa